# Best practice with mutex in C/FreeRTOS

Tags: c, mutex, freertos

i would like to better grasp the overall concept and pratical use of Mutex.
I'm currently developing a firmware which contains an http deamon thread (which comes from the vendor sdk) which serves sensors data through an internal webpage. This daemon is launched as a thread with priority 3.
In order to sample these sensors data e.g. Temperature, Humidity ecc i have a second thread that runs with priority 1 which operates through adc or i2c with the sensors.
Below a picture for better representing the situation

[image: Architecture]

Now since i don't/can't used queues what i was thinking to do was to create a struct of data with a mutex as a field as well with which i'm supposed to lock on to whenever i either read or write values to these fields. Keep in mind that the handlers are "on-event" basically. The data history are periodic and so is the sensing thread. i2c and adc are "returning" values to the sensing thread.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Do not use a mutex to manage comms with interrupt drivers.  Why can you not use a queue struct and a semaphore to signal a new entry?

Comment: @MartinJames What do you need the semaphore for? It is not needed in this case

Comment: What do you mean comms with interrupt drivers? I2c and ADC are handled by the sensing thread. What i Need is to coordinate the data access between sensing, EEPROM and http on-event requests